# Spark Streaming Context blocking REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on a small project using Spring Boot, Kafka, and Spark. So far I have been able to create a Kafka producer in one project and a Spark-Kafka direct stream as a consumer.

I am able to see messages pass through and things seem to be working as intended. However, I have a rest endpoint on the project that is running the consumer. Whenever I disable the Direct Stream, the endpoint works fine. However when I have the stream running, Postman says there is no response. I see nothing in the server logs indicating that a request was ever received either.

The Spark consumer is started by a bean at project launch. Is this keeping the normal server on localhost:8080 from being started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was kicking off the StreamingContext by annotating it as a Bean. I instead made the application implement CommandLineRunner, and in the overridden run method, I called the method that kicks off the Streaming Context. That allowed Apache to start and fixed the issue.